# variable assignment in Golang

Tags: go

So I have the two following methods:

```
func Marshal(in interface{}) (out []byte, err error)
func readDocument(r io.Reader) ([]byte, error)
```

In my code I do the following:

```
queryDoc, err := readDocument(client) // querydoc is slice of len 408
if something {
    queryDoc, err := bson.Marshal(something) 
    newDocLen := len(queryDoc) // len is now 200
}
len(queryDoc) // len is 408????
```

For some reason, queryDoc doesn't get updated with the unmarshalling. If however, I assign to an intermediate value, it works:

```
queryDoc, err := readDocument(client) // querydoc is slice of len 408
if something {
    q, err := bson.Marshal(something)
    queryDoc = q
    newDocLen := len(queryDoc) // len is now 200
}
len(queryDoc) // len is 200
```

Since I'm assigning the return value to queryDoc in the first example, shouldn't the variable queryDoc now reference the new array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In

```
queryDoc, err := bson.Marshal(something)
```

you actually created a new `queryDoc` with `:=` instead of `=`. The compiler didn't catch it because you have used it as well. Replace that with

```
var err error
queryDoc, err = bson.Marshal(something)
```

and it should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks for catching that!  I'm a golang newbie and wasn't sure if this was some crazy nuance that was different than C.  Still trying to get the hang of the := vs =.  I keep wanting to use := every time I do an assignment.